# How to input password on command prompt using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, passwords, command-prompt

I've created a procedure on VBA (Excel) that restarts services on remote servers calling the command prompt and executing the "runas" command. I need to enter the command on the servers as administrator. So far it works fine but I don't want to have to type my password for each I want to run the command in. I know how I can automate the task using VBA and the Excel. What I don't know is how could I input my password on the command prompt using VBA?

Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had all sorts of issues trying to convince `runas` to let me specify passwords from a program.

In the end, I tossed it and downloaded [`psexec`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from the [Microsoft Windows Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals) site, which has other good stuff as well.

While many see this as a tool running remote programs, it can also be used quite happily to run local stuff under a different user name while allowing you to specify the password as a command-line argument, such as:

```
psexec -d -u USER -p PWD -w WORKDIR EXECUTABLE
```

You should be able to create a textbox control in VBA with the input mask set to password, this will allow you to enter the password in a non-viewable fashion.

Then you can just construct the `psexec` command and execute it from VBA, without having to worry about injecting the password into the process running `runas`.